# SHORTEST method for finding the third vertex of an equilateral triangle given two vertices?

Tags: geometry

I know the usual method of calculating third vertex by using distance formula , forming quadratic and solving and stuff ,  but i was wondering if there was a shortcut method for finding it without much havoc ?

Eg: Equilateral triangle ABC , A(3,2) and B(5,1) find third vertex C?

I tried by considering two circles centred at A,B respectively but ended up with another hopeless equation , how do i approach this kinds of questions analytically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

midpoint of $AB$ = $(4, 1.5)$
slope of $AB = -\frac{1}{2} $

right bisector of $AB$ ... $(y-1.5)=2(x-4)$

parametrize bisector ... $$\vec \ell(t)= (4, 1.5) + \frac{t}{\sqrt 5}(1,2)  $$ where I have put in the factor of $\sqrt 5$ so that the distance from (4, 1.5) is given by $|t|$

now the altitude of an equilateral triangle is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ times the length of each side ( in this case $\sqrt 5$)

so the co-ordinates of the point $C$ will be given by $\vec\ell( \frac{\pm\sqrt{15}}{2})$

Comment: Oh the parameterised ordinates never crossed my mind , thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Well given $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$.
We know the midpoint is $M({x_1+x_2\over2},{y_1+y_2\over2})$.

Now we know the slope of $AB$ is $u=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)$ so the perpendicular slope is $v=(y_1-y_2,x_2-x_1)$ and the unit perpendicular slope is $v_1=\sqrt{(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2}\cdot(y_1-y_2,x_2-x_1)$.

And hence the third vertex is $C=M+v_1\cdot \sqrt3$. (There are going to be two $C$s)

Comment: Where does the √3 come from?